# log4g root logger with several appenderRef with markerFilters does not work

Tags: java, log4j

i have the following configuration of log4j logger ,and the appenders defined in root does not work.(it does nit log in root appenders ServerAppender and ServerAppenderV2)

i have appenders with markerFilters ,and depending on the marker , i would like to log in one or other serverLog.

in all i have 6 file appenders ,2 file appenders for application logging
2 for perf logging
2 others for server logging

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<Configuration monitorInterval="30" status="WARN">


-<Properties>

<Property name="LOG_PATTERN"> %d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSS};%p---[%t];%X{Severite}%X{IdTrace};%m;%X{Cause} %n </Property>

<Property name="PERF_LOG_PATTERN">%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS};%5p;%t;%m;%n </Property>

</Properties>


-<Appenders>


-<RollingFile name="ServerAppender" filePattern="/path/logs/server-appli-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log" fileName="/path/logs/server-appli.log">


-<PatternLayout>

<Pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</Pattern>

</PatternLayout>


-<Policies>

<TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>

</Policies>

</RollingFile>


-<RollingFile name="ServerAppenderV2" filePattern="/path/logs/server-appliV2-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log" fileName="/path/logs/server-appliV2.log">


-<PatternLayout>

<Pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</Pattern>

</PatternLayout>


-<Policies>

<TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>

</Policies>

</RollingFile>


-<RollingFile name="FileAppender" filePattern="/path/logs/appli-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log" fileName="/path/logs/appli.log">


-<PatternLayout>

<Pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</Pattern>

</PatternLayout>


-<Policies>

<TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>

</Policies>

</RollingFile>


-<RollingFile name="FileAppenderV2" filePattern="/path/logs/appliV2-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log" fileName="/path/logs/appliV2.log">


-<PatternLayout>

<Pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</Pattern>

</PatternLayout>


-<Policies>

<TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>

</Policies>

</RollingFile>


-<RollingFile name="PerfAppender" filePattern="/path/logs/perf-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log" fileName="/path/logs/perf.log">


-<PatternLayout>

<Pattern>${PERF_LOG_PATTERN}</Pattern>

</PatternLayout>


-<Policies>

<TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>

</Policies>

</RollingFile>


-<RollingFile name="PerfAppenderV2" filePattern="/path/logs/perfV2-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log" fileName="/path/logs/perfV2.log">


-<PatternLayout>

<Pattern>${PERF_LOG_PATTERN}</Pattern>

</PatternLayout>


-<Policies>

<TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>

</Policies>

</RollingFile>

</Appenders>


-<Loggers>


-<AsyncLogger name="dz.entity.pp" additivity="false" level="debug">


-<AppenderRef ref="FileAppender">

<MarkerFilter onMismatch="DENY" onMatch="ACCEPT" marker="MARK_V1"/>

</AppenderRef>


-<AppenderRef ref="FileAppenderV2">

<MarkerFilter onMismatch="DENY" onMatch="ACCEPT" marker="MARK_V2"/>

</AppenderRef>


-<AppenderRef ref="PerfAppender">

<MarkerFilter onMismatch="DENY" onMatch="ACCEPT" marker="perf"/>

</AppenderRef>


-<AppenderRef ref="PerfAppenderV2">

<MarkerFilter onMismatch="DENY" onMatch="ACCEPT" marker="perfV2"/>

</AppenderRef>

</AsyncLogger>


-<Root level="debug">


-<AppenderRef ref="ServerAppender">

<MarkerFilter onMismatch="DENY" onMatch="ACCEPT" marker="MARK_V1"/>

</AppenderRef>


-<AppenderRef ref="ServerAppenderV2">

<MarkerFilter onMismatch="DENY" onMatch="ACCEPT" marker="MARK_V2"/>

</AppenderRef>

</Root>

</Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

thanks by advance

Comment: What's the error / issue ? Please share all the relevant details.

Comment: hello , the issue is that it does not log in root appenders ServerAppender and ServerAppenderV2